# Write HTML code with JavaScript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I've seen that you can dynamically add HTML with jquery:

```
$( "div" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

What would be the way to dynamically add somewhat more complicated HTML:

```
<blockquote class="col-sm-9">
  <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <footer>Lorem Ipsum <cite title="Source Title">Lorem Ipsum</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: depends on use case ... numerous ways to do it. Can clone existing. Can use template scripts. Can use strings. Can put html in a script tag and pull it from there. Can use ajax from server. What are you trying to do?

Comment: does it matter if the html is complicated ? cant you simply use the class name to append whatever html is

Comment: i mean if we put your html in hidden div and retrieve your html as `var Your_HTML=$(".ur_hidden_div_class").html();` and than append it whereever

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is how I normally do it (simple and readable), unless there is an id in the markup

```
var html = '<blockquote class="col-sm-9">';
html += '<p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum</p>';
html += '<footer>Lorem Ipsum <cite title="Source Title">Lorem Ipsum</cite></footer>';
html += '</blockquote>'

$( "div" ).append( html );
```

if you also want to assign unique id while appending it then

```
var blockQuoteCounter = 0;
var html = '<blockquote class="col-sm-9" id="blockQuote_' + blockQuoteCounter + '">';
html += '<p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum</p>';
html += '<footer>Lorem Ipsum <cite title="Source Title">Lorem Ipsum</cite></footer>';
html += '</blockquote>'

$( "div" ).append( html );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>sample Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            var szData = "";
            szData = '<blockquote class="col-sm-9">  <p class="lead">Lorem Ipsum</p>';
            szData = szData + '<footer>Lorem Ipsum <cite title="Source Title">Lorem Ipsum</cite>';
            szData = szData + '</footer></blockquote>';

            $('div').append(szData)
        });



    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Add Data" id="btnAdd"/>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a answer for how to display html code in javascript

> $( "#update" ).append( 'You have 5 tokens remaining for this coupon. Would you like to Update the unused tokens? Please select quantity you would like to Update.”{{ csrf_field() }} Update Coupon Quantity. Recover Unused Coupon.Close');